# Qt QGraphicsScene add and delete lines

Tags: c++, qt

I am (very) new to Qt and I am trying to make a simple plot (without involving external libraries&co), which also has a box, axes, and grid lines, which I want to be able to toggle.

I have the `QGraphicsScene` defined as `scene` where I can use `scene->addLine(...)`, but I don't know how I can remove those lines based on a `QCheckBox`. This is (in short) what I have set in the function `plotAxes()` which will be used with `connect()`:

```
    QGraphicsLineItem *xAxis {new QGraphicsScene::addLine(xMin, 0, xMax, 0, *dashedLine)};
    if (boxToggle->isChecked())
    {
        scene->addItem(xAxis);
        //scene->addLine(yCenter, yMin, yCenter, yMax, *dashedLine);
        scene->update();
    }
    else
    {
        scene->removeItem(xAxis);
        scene->update();
    }
```

The code only shows the first axis, if it works for that I can extend to everything else, but it doesn't work. For `xAxis` I tried `QGraphicsItem`, `QGraphicsScene`, combinations, but this isn't how I want to continue. I don't know how to add the line (axis) as a variable, or pointer, and then use that to add/delete to/from the scene. Can someone please tell me how to do it?

---

[edit]
I'm sorry, forgot to say I want to be able to toggle them without affecting what's already plotted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have fixed amount of lines, you can store them as member variables and the problem becomes trivial. But I'm going to assume the number of lines can vary. I'm also assuming you have a separate checkbox for each line you wish to show/hide. What you want to do, is use the [`toggled`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) signal of your checkboxes to hide/show your lines. You can use a `QSignalMapper` to do this, but I recommend using a lambda expression.

I put an example below that you can just copy-paste and run. Now in this example I used a lambda expression, which requires `c++11`. If you are using Qt 5.7 *(or newer for future reference)*, I think it is enabled automatically. But if you're using an older version, you'll have to add `CONFIG += c++11` in your `.pro` file.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QGraphicsLineItem>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget()
    {
        resize(600, 400);
        setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
        view = new QGraphicsView;
        scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        view->setScene(scene);
        layout()->addWidget(view);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            QGraphicsLineItem *line = scene->addLine(0, i * 20, width(), i * 20, Qt::DashLine);
            lines.append(line);

            QCheckBox *checkbox = new QCheckBox(QString("Show line %1").arg(i+1));
            connect(checkbox, &QCheckBox::toggled, [=](bool toggled){line->setVisible(toggled);});
            layout()->addWidget(checkbox);
            checkbox->setChecked(true);
        }
    }

private:
    QGraphicsView *view;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QVector<QGraphicsLineItem*> lines;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I copy-pasted the code to get a feel on it, but with Qtcreator 4.0.3, Qt 5.7.0, arch x64, it says `undefined reference to 'vtable for Widget'`. I added the `c++11` line, to be sure, but it's the same. I had to comment the last `.moc` line, `no such file or directory`. Is this the cause? Also, imagine a plot window that has XY axes, configurable number of grid lines, and a box, a rectangle to fit them all. These I want added/deleted without touching the already plotted lines, so they are fixed in number. Maybe this helps?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Run qmake first, then try building.

Comment: Then you can store most of them just as member variables, and connect a signal to a slot and hide/show those in that slot. So you don't have to use a `QVector` like I did in the example. You can also use slots instead of lambda expressions. Just make a slot for every checkbox you have that shows/hides something.

Comment: Now it works, I was relying on Qtcreator to do it. Beginner... Thank you for the example, it works nicely, but I'll first have to read about the lambda function to better understand it, though it seems pretty self-explanatory. I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: That was what I couldn't do in the OP, but now I see that you use `setVisible()` instead of `removeItem()`. I think it'll work, either way, I'll just have to practise some more.