# Qt QGraphicsScene show/hide axes

Tags: c++, qt

This is a continuation from [Qt QGraphicsScene add and delete lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738603/qt-qgraphicsscene-add-and-delete-lines) . I thought I could do it, but I can't. The window shows up, but no matter how many times I check/uncheck, the axes only show up once and never get hidden or toggled; they stay on after the first "on" check.

I added a `qDebug(toggled ? "1" : "0")`, it correctly shows the `toggled`'s value changing from `0` to `1` and vice-versa for every click on the check box, but the axes only stay on after they're turned on. I only started Qt about a week ago (and C++ about a month ago), at this point I don't know what to believe.

In the linked question, thuga uses the `connect()` inside the loop and only takes care of one line, but that one line is toggled. I also tried making the function `bool`, returning `toggled`, but it's the same thing. It's as if `setVisible(false)` doesn't work.

Here's what I have (replace xy variables with whatever you want):

[public slot]

```
void plotAxes()
{
    QPen *dashedLine {new QPen(QBrush(Qt::blue), 1, Qt::DashLine)};
    QGraphicsLineItem *xAxis {scene->addLine(xMin, 0, xMax, 0, *dashedLine)};
    QGraphicsLineItem *yAxis {scene->addLine(yCenter, yMin, yCenter, yMax, *dashedLine)};
    bool toggled {axesToggle->isChecked()};
    if (!toggled)
    {
        xAxis->setVisible(false);
        yAxis->setVisible(false);
    }
    else
    {
        xAxis->setVisible(true);
        yAxis->setVisible(true);
    }
    scene->update();
}
```

`axesToggle` is a `QCheckBox`, and its `connect()` function is:

```
connect(axesToggle, &QCheckBox::toggled, this, &PlotBox::plotAxes);
```

where `PlotBox` is the class. In addition there are also `boxToggle` and `gridToggle`, but there's no point in going forward if this doesn't work.

---

[edit]

To better show what I have, here's a screenshot of the app:
[image: qtapp]

It started by trying `QGraphicsView` with a simple `sinc()`, then moved on to an Octave's `stem`-like plot, then I kept adding to practise Qt (I am only just learning it) -- ignore the weird dashed grid lines for now. What it currently does is it automatically updates the plot after any +/- click on the `sinc() settings` spinboxes, or selecting the `Plot style`, it has a key shortcut to toggle antialiasing, it can zoom with `Ctrl+MouseWheel`, can correctly reset view. So now I thought I'd add the possibility of toggling the grid&co, while also allowing a setting for the grid lines.

Now I managed to get results by giving up on the public slot function and making `connect()` as thuga did in the previous answer. This is inside the `PlotBox()` constructor (`PlotBox` being the class).

```
QPen *dashedLine {new QPen(QBrush(Qt::blue), 1, Qt::DashLine)};
QGraphicsLineItem *xAxis {scene->addLine(xMin, 0, xMax, 0, *dashedLine)};
QGraphicsLineItem *yAxis {scene->addLine(yCenter, yMin, yCenter, yMax, *dashedLine)};
connect(axesToggle, &QCheckBox::toggled, [=](bool toggled){xAxis->setVisible(toggled); yAxis->setVisible(toggled)});
```

and it works *only if* the xy variables are simple values (as in `int a {value}`), but they are dependent on the `sinc() settings` spinboxes; I use `orderN = orderSet->value()` for setting `N`, which is used to calculate the xy variables, for example. So the above will only work if I don't make changes to the plot.

If I want them to be in sync with the `sinc() settings`, then I have to make it like this:

```
orderN = static_cast<short>(orderSet->value());
spacingS = static_cast<short>(spacingSet->value());
plotHeight = static_cast<short>(heightSet->value());
int xMin {-spacingS};
int xMax {orderN*spacingS};
int yMin {plotHeight>>2};
int yMax {-plotHeight};
double yCenter {(orderN-1)*spacingS*0.5};
QPen *dashedLine {new QPen(QBrush(Qt::blue), 1, Qt::DashLine)};
QGraphicsLineItem *xAxis {scene->addLine(xMin, 0, xMax, 0, *dashedLine)};
QGraphicsLineItem *yAxis {scene->addLine(yCenter, yMin, yCenter, yMax, *dashedLine)};
connect(axesToggle, &QCheckBox::toggled, [=](bool toggled){xAxis->setVisible(toggled); yAxis->setVisible(toggled)});
```

and this will also work, but only if I don't make any change to any of the `sinc() settings` spinboxes. If I do and I try to toggle the axes, it crashes, because `xMin`&co are dynamically used by the `Plot style` functions, when they are called -- they each modify the values locally. This results in a value mismatch.

So, if it only needs to adapt the spinboxes values, then I transformed it into a function for it, alone, like this:

```
void plotAxes(const bool &toggled)
{
    orderN = static_cast<short>(orderSet->value());
    spacingS = static_cast<short>(spacingSet->value());
    plotHeight = static_cast<short>(heightSet->value());
    int xMin {-spacingS};
    int xMax {orderN*spacingS};
    int yMin {plotHeight>>2};
    int yMax {-plotHeight};
    double yCenter {(orderN-1)*spacingS*0.5};
    QPen *dashedLine {new QPen(QBrush(Qt::blue), 1, Qt::DashLine)};
    QGraphicsLineItem *xAxis {scene->addLine(xMin, 0, xMax, 0, *dashedLine)};
    QGraphicsLineItem *yAxis {scene->addLine(yCenter, yMin, yCenter, yMax, *dashedLine)};
        xAxis->setVisible(toggled);
        yAxis->setVisible(toggled);
        //qDebug(toggled ? "1" : "0"); // this correctly shows "toggled" changing values
    scene->update();
}
```

which I called with `connect()` like this:

```
connect(axesToggle, &QCheckBox::toggled, [=](bool toggled){plotAxes(toggled);});
```

This one uses the same `xAxis->setVisible(toggle)` as the above, yet it doesn't work. It will only show the axes when the `Axes` checkbox is checked, then they stay on until I make changes to the plot, then they can again be toggled on, but that's it.

The whole `main.cpp` is about 370 lines long. If it's needed, I can post it to pastebin. It's most probably the most childish code you'll ever see, but I'm just learning.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by making `xAxis` and `yAxis` private variables, then using a member function `updateValues()` dealing with all the necessary other variables, as well, function which is called by each of the private slot functions `plotImpulses()`, `plotLines()`, and `plotSteps()`, thus reusing the values, and then keeping the `connect()` as:

```
    connect(axesToggle, \
            &QCheckBox::toggled, \
            [=](bool toggled)
            {
                xAxis->setVisible(toggled);
                yAxis->setVisible(toggled);
            });
```

at the end of the constructor, after which I only need to call the default plot style (`plotImpulses()`) in order for the values to be updated. This should only happen once with the constructor (right?). Now, anytime there's a change in the plot, `updateValues()` gets called through the plot style functions, which means toggling the axes (+box+grid) is done with fresh updated values from the spinboxes. I'm not sure how orthodox it is what I did, or how much overhead or room for optimization there is, so suggestions are most welcome.